# IF/THEN Statement for NULL values

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am not sure how I can implement an IF/THEN statement in my code.

In the first query I'm creating a table that 1) has dengue cases, 2) concatenates all lab results, 3) creates a travel variable where if the case travelled it will pull the travel location, if they did not then it will be null. From that table, the second query is keeping the last case per day, so removing all earlier cases per day.

There are some cases that are identical in time but have two different travel values. I would like to keep all data that 1) has the most recent InsertedDateTime (this can have NULL travel values), 2) if they have identical time values, then it will keep the case that has a travel value not equal to "NULL".

Ideally, I would like to add a statement that says, "if rn=1 and travel = “NULL” then delete”. Seeing that I'm new to SQL and code predominately in SAS, I'm not sure where this should go or how it would be correctly written. Thanks in advance for not being rude and understanding I'm new (ya'll are pretty harsh). Also, I have no control over how the servers or databases are named.

Example Data:

PatientFirstName    PatientLastName PatientDOB  InsertedDateTime    FacilityName    FacilityAddressCounty   EncounterDateFrom   Reason eCR reported Lab results Travel

Jane    Doe 20000101    2/12/2023 16:19 BHospital   OldCounty   2/2/2023 8:20   Dengue Virus Infection (as a diagnosis or active problem),Fever (Temperature = 38°C [100.4°F])  NULL    NULL

Jane    Doe 20000101    2/12/2023 16:19 BHospital   OldCounty   2/2/2023 8:20   Dengue Virus Infection (as a diagnosis or active problem),Fever (Temperature = 38°C [100.4°F])  NULL    Mexico

```
    DROP Table IF EXISTS #labs 
    SELECT ecr_FK, ObservationResultTypeDisplayName, 
     ObservationResultValueType, ObservationResultValue,        
    ObservationResultValueUnit
    INTO #labs  
    FROM ecr.ecr.dbo.Results 
    where InsertedDateTime >= '2021-01-03' and 
    ObservationResultTypeDisplayName like '%dengue%'
    CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_Results_FK ON #labs (eCR_FK) 


    DROP Table IF EXISTS #ReportabilityRules 
    SELECT *  
    INTO #ReportabilityRules  
    FROM ecr.ecr.dbo.ReportabilityRules 
    CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_RR_FK ON #ReportabilityRules (RR_FK) 

    DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #ALL
    select  eCR_PK, a.PatientFirstName, a.PatientLastName, a.PatientDOB, a.InsertedDateTime, 
    a.FacilityName, a.FacilityAddressCounty,a.EncounterDateFrom, s.codeDisplayName
    ,(SELECT CASE WHEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY rr2.RR_fk) = 1 THEN rr2.reportabilityRules ELSE ', ' +    rr2.reportabilityRules END 
         FROM #ReportabilityRules rr2 WHERE d.RR_pk=rr2.RR_fk 
         FOR XML PATH('')) [Reason eCR reported] 
    ,(SELECT CASE WHEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY l2.eCR_fk) = 1 THEN   concat(l2.ObservationResultTypeDisplayName, ' ', l2.ObservationResultValueType, ' ', l2.ObservationResultValue, ' ', l2.ObservationResultValueUnit)  ELSE ', ' + concat(l2.ObservationResultTypeDisplayName, ' ', l2.ObservationResultValueType, ' ', l2.ObservationResultValue, ' ', l2.ObservationResultValueUnit)  END 
         FROM #labs l2 WHERE l1.eCR_FK=l2.eCR_FK 
         FOR XML PATH('')) [Lab results] 
,case when s.codeDisplayName like '%travel%' then s.obsValue else NULL END [Travel]

    INTO #ALL
    from ecr.dbo.ecr a with (NOLOCK)
    left join ecr.dbo.RR d on a.eCR_PK=d.eCR_FK 
    left join #labs l1 on l1.eCR_FK=a.eCR_PK
    left join eCR.ecr.dbo.social s on s.eCR_FK=a.eCR_PK
    where ConditionDisplayName like '%dengue%' and a.InsertedDateTime >= '2021-01-03'


   select distinct PatientFirstName, PatientLastName, PatientDOB, InsertedDateTime, FacilityName,  FacilityAddressCounty, EncounterDateFrom, [Reason eCR reported], [Lab results], [Travel]
    from 
    (select *,
   ROW_NUMBER () over (partition by patientdob, cast(inserteddatetime as date)
order by inserteddatetime desc) as rn
   from #ALL
   ) as ecr_date 
   where rn=1
```

Comment: There are temp tables. Are you saying you don't know in your code if a temp table exists? This has a lot of code smell to it. This looks like perhaps a cte would be more appropriate than all these temp tables.

Comment: We need to see sample data and desired results

Comment: Please learn how to ask question here. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I must admit, I must be pretty confusing to have a linked server called `ecr` as well as a database both locally on remotely called `ecr`. I took me a couple passes to realise that `ecr` meant *three* different things in your code.

Comment: One possibility is to just make the subquery where you have your `row_number()` defined a predicate like `where [Travel] is not null`. You won't technically be getting the most recent record by `inserteddatetime`, but it will give you a record with a `Travel` value. Alternatively, if you don't care about getting arbitrary `Travel` values, you could replace the `row_number` with a `group by` and project up the fields you want, like, for example `max(Travel)`. Just make sure you understand what you're doing with Group bys if you go that route

Comment: Agree with @ThomA. Your linked server name should be the *name* of the server you are linking to.

Comment: Your code is a mess... Make it easy to assist you - simplify! A [mcve] is a great start when asking for SQL assistance.

Comment: Sorry, I can't change my server or database names. That is not within the scope of my position.

Comment: The use of `distinct` is a red flag in my book. **`Distinct` is rarely the solution to unexpected duplicate data.** Often its use can appear to improve the results, but it actually hides the real problem. I suggest that you remove the `distinct`  and take another look at the results. If you see multiple rows where you expect only one, first look for under-constrained joins or multiple independent one-to-many joins. After that, consider using `GROUP BY` on the key columns, together with `MAX()` or `SUM()` (or other aggregating functions) to combine multiple values in other columns.

Comment: (continued) If you use `GROUP BY` instead of `DISTINCT`, you might be able to redefine your `Travel` column using *conditional aggregation*. Something like `SUM(CASE WHEN s.codeDisplayName LIKE '%travel%' THEN s.obsValue END) Travel` or `MAX(CASE WHEN s.codeDisplayName LIKE '%travel%' THEN s.obsValue END) Travel`. (Note: The `ELSE NULL` is an implied default in a `CASE` expression and has been omitted.)

Comment: Side note: In SQL Server 2017 and later, your `[Reason eCR reported]` and `[Lab results]` can be simplified using STRING_AGG() in place of the long-used FOR XML technique.   For example `,(SELECT STRING_AGG(rr2.reportabilityRules, ', ') WITHIN GROUP(ORDER BY rr2.RR_fk) FROM #ReportabilityRules rr2 WHERE d.RR_pk=rr2.RR_fk) [Reason eCR reported]`. Same result, but arguably more readable. You might want to reexamine the `ORDER BY rr2.RR_fk` part though. As I read the subquery, that value will be the same for all values due to the `WHERE` condition.

Comment: Duplicate data may be the result of NOLOCK. That hint doesn't mean Go Fast, it means ignore locks, reading duplicate or incomplete data while randomly throwing. You need to read [Bad Habits to Break: NOLOCK Everywhere](https://www.sentryone.com/blog/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere).

Comment: The way the query is written, it will pull all data from the linked server locally before joining and filtering it. NOLOCK won't fix this. Check [Techniques to Enhance Linked Server Performance](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-database-support-blog/techniques-to-enhance-linked-server-performance/ba-p/1804527)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

BLUF: The problem is not in the ROW_NUMBER() filter logic in the final select, but in the JOIN logic of the preceding query that feeds the #ALL table.

After a deep dive into your posted code, my understanding is that you are gathering information on who has contracted a Dengue Virus Infection and what countries have these patients recently traveled to.

I see what appears to be **three independent one-to-many joins** in the query that feeds the `#ALL` temp table - `ecr.dbo.RR`, `#labs`, and `eCR.ecr.dbo.social`. This is likely the primary cause of the duplicate/conflicting rows that you are attempting to resolve.

The #labs join can be eliminated outright. Its only use is already contained within the `[Lab results]` subquery. The `ecr.dbo.RR` join can also be eliminated from the outer query if you include it as a `JOIN` in the `[Reason eCR reported]` subquery.

This leaves the `eCR.ecr.dbo.social` table. Two columns are referenced from this table - `codeDisplayName` and `obsValue`. The `codeDisplayName` column is referenced in the `#ALL` query, but the resulting value is not used by the final select. If it were used, I might suggest a STRING_AGG() concatenation like for `[Lab results]`and `[Reason eCR reported]`. But since it is unused, I believe it can just be eliminated outright.

As for `obsValue`, this depends on whether or not there can be more than one record (per patient encounter) with `s.codeDisplayName like '%travel%'` and how you need to handle potential multiple eligible obsValue values. One option is to move the `Travel` calculation into a subquery like `[Reason eCR reported]` and `[Lab results]` that calculates an aggregate value (typically `MAX()`, `SUM()`, or `STRING_AGG()`). Another option is to use a `OUTER APPLY(SELECT TOP 1 ... ORDER BY...)` to pick at most a single row and use its value.

For now, I am guessing that the travel `obsValue` value is a string value, possibly a country name. In that case, if there is more than one matching travel record representing multiple travel destinations, I expect we would want to use `STRING_AGG()` to get them all.

The rewritten `#ALL` query might be like the following:

```
select
    eCR_PK, a.PatientFirstName, a.PatientLastName, a.PatientDOB, a.InsertedDateTime, 
    a.FacilityName, a.FacilityAddressCounty,a.EncounterDateFrom, s.codeDisplayName
    ,(SELECT STRING_AGG(rr2.reportabilityRules, ', ')
             WITHIN GROUP(ORDER BY rr2.RR_fk) -- Is there a better order by value?
         FROM ecr.dbo.RR d 
         JOIN #ReportabilityRules rr2 ON d.RR_pk = rr2.RR_fk 
         WHERE on a.eCR_PK = d.eCR_FK
         ) [Reason eCR reported] 
    ,(SELECT STRING_AGG(
             concat(
                l2.ObservationResultTypeDisplayName,
                ' ', l2.ObservationResultValueType,
                ' ', l2.ObservationResultValue,
                ' ', l2.ObservationResultValueUnit)
             , ', ')
             WITHIN GROUP(ORDER BY l2.eCR_fk) -- Is there a better order by value?
         FROM #labs l2
         WHERE l1.eCR_FK = l2.eCR_FK
         ) [Lab results] 
    ,(SELECT STRING_AGG(s.obsValue, ', ')
             WITHIN GROUP(ORDER BY s.???) -- What is the best order by value?
         FROM eCR.ecr.dbo.social s
         WHERE s.eCR_FK = a.eCR_PK
         AND s.codeDisplayName like '%travel%'
         ) [Travel]
INTO #ALL
from ecr.dbo.ecr a with (NOLOCK)
where ConditionDisplayName like '%dengue%'
and a.InsertedDateTime >= '2021-01-03'
```

I've eliminated all of the one-to-many joins from the outer query, converted the `FOR XML` subqueries to use `STRING_AGG()`, and added a few newlines for easier reading.

The above is not tested (we have no posted sample data) and might need some tweaks. In particular, the `STRING_AGG() ... ORDER BY` clauses need to be reviewed and appropriate sort column referenced selected.

As for the final select, I believe you shoudl be able to eliminate the `DISTINCT`. I do have a concern about the `ROW_NUMBER() ...partition by ...`. Since `patientdob` is not necessarily unique to the patient, I would suggest also including `PatientFirstName` and `PatientLastName` as a minimum. Even that is not guaranteed. If you can access a patient ID in your source data, using that would be more reliable.

Since `eCR.ecr.dbo.social` is a remote table reference, there may be a need to preselect that data (within the relevant date range) and pull it to a local temp table to avoid excessive cross-server accesses.

If you have further clarifications on your requirements, add them to your original post and/or add a comment below and I will look at updating this answer.

Answer (score 0):

CASE WHEN expressions can be used to do inline column level "if this then that" type of logic.

Example

```
 "if rn=1 and travel = “NULL” then delete”.
```

Would be

```
 CASE
      WHEN rn = 1 and travel IS NULL THEN 'delete'
 END
```

Now I don't understand what you're actually asking is but I think this will help you get there. If you're trying to remove these rows from the table #ALL, then I think it might be best to do your ROW_NUMBER() in the previous query and filter out by these two conditions you have.

Comment: First, thank you for the help. Second, I don't think the CASE WHEN expression you wrote would work in the previous query because "rn" is created in the second query. I'll try and make my question clearer. In the first query I'm creating a table that 1) has dengue cases, 2) concatenates all lab results, 3) creates a travel variable where if the case traveled it will pull the travel location, if they did not then it will be null. From that table, the second query is keeping the last case per day, so removing all earlier cases per day.

Comment: From that table, I would like to remove the last case per day if they their travel data is "NULL". Hopefully that is clearer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It's really hard to be more specific without example DDL/DML here's an example of that:

```
ECLARE @Table TABLE (TravelDateTime DATETIME, TravelCity NVARCHAR(50), TravelCost DECIMAL(10,2));
INSERT INTO @Table (TravelDateTime, TravelCity, TravelCost) VALUES
('2023-01-01 00:05', NULL, NULL), ('2023-01-01 00:10', 'London',   NULL), ('2023-01-01 00:15', 'London',   123.45), ('2023-01-01 00:20', 'London',   678.90),
('2023-01-02 00:05', NULL, NULL), ('2023-01-02 00:10', 'New York', NULL), ('2023-01-02 00:15', 'New York', 123.45), ('2023-01-02 00:20', 'New York', 678.90);
```

I realize this simplifies your question down a lot, but as an example of what I think you're shooting for:

```
SELECT TravelDateTime, TravelCity, TravelCost   
  FROM (
        SELECT TravelDateTime, TravelCity, TravelCost, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY CAST(TravelDateTime AS DATE) ORDER BY CASE WHEN TravelCity IS NULL OR TravelCost IS NULL THEN CAST('9999-12-31 23:59:59.997' AS DATETIME) ELSE TravelDateTime END) AS RowNumber
          FROM @Table
       ) a
 WHERE RowNumber = 1;
```

Here we're assigning a Row Number for each row, partition by the date and then ordered by the date and time, unless one, or both, of the columns we care about are null, in which case we treat it as the end of time. Then the outer query only returns the earliest datetime for that date, that has non-nulls in both columns.

| TravelDateTime | TravelCity | TravelCost |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-01-01 00:15:00.000 | London | 123.45 |
| 2023-01-02 00:15:00.000 | New York | 123.45 |

Example using OPs example data (assumed data types) provided in the comments (assuming partition on first, last and DOB):

```
DECLARE @Table TABLE (PatientFirstName NVARCHAR(50), PatientLastName NVARCHAR(50), PatientDOB DATE, InsertedDateTime DATETIME, FacilityName NVARCHAR(50), FacilityAddressCounty NVARCHAR(50), 
                      EncounterDateFrom DATETIME, [Reason eCR reported Lab] NVARCHAR(500), results NVARCHAR(50), Travel  NVARCHAR(50)
)
INSERT INTO @Table (PatientFirstName, PatientLastName, PatientDOB, InsertedDateTime, FacilityName, FacilityAddressCounty, EncounterDateFrom, [Reason eCR reported Lab], results, Travel) VALUES
('Jane', 'Doe', '20000101', '2/12/2023 16:19', 'BHospital', 'OldCounty', '2/2/2023 8:20', 'Dengue Virus Infection (as a diagnosis or active problem),Fever (Temperature = 38°C [100.4°F])', NULL, NULL), 
('Jane', 'Doe', '20000101', '2/12/2023 16:19', 'BHospital', 'OldCounty', '2/2/2023 8:20', 'Dengue Virus Infection (as a diagnosis or active problem),Fever (Temperature = 38°C [100.4°F])', NULL, 'Mexico');

SELECT PatientFirstName, PatientLastName, PatientDOB, InsertedDateTime, FacilityName, FacilityAddressCounty, EncounterDateFrom, [Reason eCR reported Lab], results, Travel
  FROM (
        SELECT PatientFirstName, PatientLastName, PatientDOB, InsertedDateTime, FacilityName, FacilityAddressCounty, EncounterDateFrom, [Reason eCR reported Lab], results, Travel, 
               ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY PatientFirstName, PatientLastName, PatientDOB ORDER BY CASE WHEN Travel IS NULL THEN '9999-12-31 23:59:59.997' ELSE InsertedDateTime END) AS RowNumber
          FROM @Table
       ) a
 WHERE RowNumber = 1;
```

| PatientFirstName | PatientLastName | PatientDOB | InsertedDateTime | FacilityName | FacilityAddressCounty | EncounterDateFrom | Reason eCR reported Lab | results | Travel |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Jane | Doe | 2000-01-01 | 2023-02-12 16:19:00.000 | BHospital | OldCounty | 2023-02-02 08:20:00.000 | Dengue Virus Infection (as a diagnosis or active problem),Fever (Temperature = 38°C [100.4°F]) |  | Mexico |

Comment: Thanks for the response. I've edited by question to try and be clearer. Here are some example data:

Comment: PatientFirstName PatientLastName PatientDOB InsertedDateTime FacilityName FacilityAddressCounty EncounterDateFrom Reason eCR reported Lab results Travel
Jane Doe 20000101 2/12/2023 16:19 BHospital  OldCounty 2/2/2023 8:20 Dengue Virus Infection (as a diagnosis or active problem),Fever (Temperature = 38°C [100.4°F]) NULL NULL
Jane Doe 20000101 2/12/2023 16:19 BHospital  OldCounty 2/2/2023 8:20 Dengue Virus Infection (as a diagnosis or active problem),Fever (Temperature = 38°C [100.4°F]) NULL Mexico

Comment: This isn't really any different than the example, but I added a version using your data.